# how to detremine why unrar is failing // file name restrictions

Tags: archive, filename

I installed ? (at least I hope so !!) unrar with

```
sudo apt-get install unrar-free
```

I tried from **Archive Manager**
**Archive Manager** displays the existence of files inside the *Archive.rar*
After the "Extract" command, it show as a dialog "extraction completed successfully"
but nothing seem to happen, the extracted file can not be found

I did a try with command line in **Terminal**
providing full path of the Archive
the result given is "Failed"

are there file name restrictions in place ?? or maybe I make some other mistake ?
is there another application able to unrar files  / able to handle *Archive.rar*  using a graphical interface  ?

Emma

Answer (score -1):

I believe `unrar` is command line only but you may want to install **Xarchiver**

You can find it in the software center.

[image]

Or install from the command line with:

```
sudo apt-get install xarchiver
```